# Testing both publishOn and subscribeOn on webflux

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, testing, spring-webflux

I have a simple method at which i am using `publishOn`

```
    restClient
            .get(baseUrl + "/id")
            .send(StatusResponse.class)
            .publishOn(ASYNC_SCHEDULER)
            .doOnSuccess(response ->logBody(response ))
            .map(response -> doSomething(response));
```

This is very simple method connecting to external service and publish the result into a synch scheduler.
How to write a viable unit/integration test or how can one test multithreads on reactive model?

Comment: I cant find `send` in the api. What is that.

Comment: restClient is my version of webClient, you can use any other service, the idea here is how to test multithreadin

Comment: why test something that the framework already has tested for you, you should be testing business logic.